# Customize SignalR to handle raw messages

Tags: signalr

I tried the SignalR(Self-Host) and seems it wraps the message with its own payload in JSON. 
Is it able to handle SignalR raw message?

1. I wanna set the WebSocket sub-protocol to "wamp"
2. I need send & receive the message in raw format as it is on client side
3. I don't need any fallback support, only WebSocket and I wanna turn off all the other fallback features

Br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, SignalR does not support WebSocket sub-protocols, It can handle strings if you use the `PersistentConnection` API, that contains a method to receive `String` :

```
Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data);
```

If you need WebSockets with a custom protocol, you can use XSocket.NET : https://github.com/XSockets